# FontLab Studio - Line Height on Font Weight Alternative

Tags: typography

I am using FontLab Studio - I have two font files - a normal and a bold alternative. Here are the two fonts side-by-side:

[image]

When I export the normal and install it it looks just like i want it to - however bold text seems to be slightly taller - making the line shift down whenever I make it bold - for instance, here are the two side by side in an invisible table:

[image]

You can see this more clearly when put into a table and compared to how Calibri behaves:

[image]

What am I missing here to make the line height of these two variations the same?

To better show exactly what I mean, see this video:
https://www.screencast.com/t/tDMt9lkwCZx

Here is a comparison of the Font Info:

**Regular**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Bold**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey @WELZ - To better show what I mean, I have added another picture and video to the description.

Comment: I’ve never used FontLab Studio, but presumably there is somewhere you can set the basic line height (or x height or something similar) for the font—does that setting have different values for the regular and the bold? @WELZ You’re comparing glyph size, rather than line/x height.

Comment: For further information, could you please produce the font metrics file (AFM) for both font weights and tell me the values of the FontBBox line in both cases please?

Comment: Wile you provided the DESIGN parameters, it would be interesting to check the CALCULATED parameters. In each font, you can click FIle > Export > Metrics, and generate the AFM, which is an ASCII (text) file. If you open it with Notepad, you can see the calculated FontBBox for the whole font.

Comment: @PepeOchoa, aren't the "Font BBox" shown at the bottom of "Key dimensions" the calculated values?

Comment: Oh! It's true! :P Hehe. Well, from the calculations, the difference in the _y_ dimension is _probably_ not enough to cause the behavior. I tested with a font family, introducing a glyph with a very, _very_ tall ascender in the bold version. It modified the FontBBox enough to cause the same behavior in Word, even when the glyph was not typed. Stray points (open contours) doesn't seem to cause the behavior on ttf (which is the format with the issue), so I have to look for other causes...

Comment: I still think that generating the AFM file would be a good idea... :/ I tried generating it for some fonts and the metrics are _very_ different from the ones shown in the properties dialog...

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

1. In `File > Font Info`, compare all values under `Metrics and Dimensions`
2. Do you export to `.otf` or `.ttf`? Does the problem persist with `.ttf`?

Let us know what you found there.

Comment: Hi @AAGD - I added some screenshots above with Font Info - both styles have the exact same values.  I am exporting with .ttf - I actually just tried exporting with .otf though and the problem is fixed - so what is wrong with my ttf setup?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not that experienced in this either, esp. on Win. Have you tried switching to "Calculate Values automatically" as recommended by the interface?